# How to decrease A-frame 360 deg image size

Tags: aframe

I want to include `<h1>` and  `<p>` tags  underneath of `a-scene`.

**eg:**

```
    <a-scene>
  <a-sky src="http://i.imgur.com/9zATQ6s.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>

  <a-text font="kelsonsans" value="Puy de Sancy, France" width="6" position="-2.5 0.25 -1.5"
          rotation="0 15 0"></a-text>
</a-scene>
<h1>test</h1>
```

now `test` is invisible in my browser.how can i show `test` and how can i decrease `a-scene`  size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use A-Frame's embedded component to resize the canvas:

`<a-scene embedded></a-scene>`

 check out the [Example](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/embedded/) / [Docs](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/embedded.md)